# Как правильно: "он подтянул ей брюки" или "он подтянул на ней брюки"?

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: "он подтянул ей брюки" или "он подтянул на ней брюки"?
(если девушка лежит без сознания с приспущенными до колен брюками)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так: *он подтянул **на ней** брюки.*

**Пояснение**

**ПОДТЯНУТЬ,** св.  4. что. Затянуть, натянуть потуже или выше, плотно прижимая к чему-л. П. седло. П. ремень. П. лопнувшую струну. П. полушубок ремнём. П. голенище сапога. **П. брюки.** П. гайки, болты.

1. В предложении использована инверсия, при прямом порядке слов это будет выглядеть так: *Он подтянул (что?) брюки (на ком?) на ней.*
2. *Подтянул (кому?) ей брюки?* Но в этом случае девушка должна находиться в сознании, как я думаю. Действие обращено к объекту.